# Comparing function calls with nested callable arguments in python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to compare two function calls using `AST`. I have an `ast.NodeVisitor` implementation which will return a dictionary with function name`(_Call.func.attr)`, argument list `(_Call.args)`, keyword arguments `(_Call.keywords)` etc.

I'm running into issues with calls having nested callable arguments. eg:

```
functionA(arg_1, callable_arg_1(callable_arg(somearg)), arg_2, arg_3)
```

How would I make a unique signature in such a scenario? I should have the flexibility to examine and compare any argument any level deep.

**Edit: Formatted code from the comment, lacking context -**

```
def visit_Call(self, obj):
    self._name =  obj.func.attr
    self._kwargs = obj.kwargs.id
    self._starargs = obj.starargs.id
    for arg in obj.args:
        self._arg_list.append(arg.id)
    for kw in obj.keywords:
        self._keyword_list.append((kw.arg, kw.value.id))
```

Comment: I don't get your question. What *is* the problem with nested calls? You didn't describe what's happening.

Comment: Each callable argument will be a call object in a tree. I wanted to see if there is a way to generate a unique signature from this whole tree, where I'll be able to compare individual subtrees. (Recursively parsing the call objects sounded like a bad idea).

Comment: I still don't get where's the problem. In fact function signatures have nothing to do with *calls*, but with definitions. Please provide the *code* you are using, the result you are obtaining and what you'd like to have as result instead.

Comment: I'm not talking about function signatures per se. In the question, I mentioned I have a dictionary with name and argument list, I want to some how incorporate nested function calls in a similar fashion (not necessarily dictionaries). I don't know how to make it any simpler. I'm not at liberty to share code here, I could share my visit function in ast.NodeVisitor I suppose

Comment: @Bakuriu 
    `def visit_Call(self, obj):
        self._name =  obj.func.attr
        self._kwargs = obj.kwargs.id
        self._starargs = obj.starargs.id
        for arg in obj.args:
            self._arg_list.append(arg.id)
        for kw in obj.keywords:
            self._keyword_list.append((kw.arg, kw.value.id))`

Comment: @bbsanem Please edit your code into your question. Large fragments of code in comments are hard to read and make interpretation prone to errors.

Comment: 1. What result do you want, in the end ? Are you willing to interprete the AST, to have an execution result ? The given code does nothing but copying values and it goal isn't clear. What is it used for ?

Comment: The end result would be used for comparison. interpretation of AST is only done while generating the signature. Later on, the signature is passed around for comparisions.